# Why do groff -Tdvi | dvipdf and groff -Tpdf produce very different results?

Tags: pdf, groff

Let's consider the following simple groff code

```
.EQ
s = sqrt { { sum from i=1 to N ( x sub i - x bar ) sup 2 } over { N - 1 } }
.EN
```

When I use the `groff -e -Tpdf` command I get the following (ugly) result:

[image: Direct PDF]

However when I use `groff -e -Tdvi` and then `dvipdf` I get a nicer result:

[image: PDF through DVI]

Why are those so different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: **Hail to thee young padawan, for honouring the ancient ways!**

The outputs are looking different because two different typesetters have been used (which used different fonts on top of that).

When using the **-Tpdf** option, the output is rendered for a *PostScript*-like typesetter(`*`) and the standard fonts (Times-Roman, Times-Italic, Symbol) are being used. The PDF document does not contain the fonts definitions but relies on the PDF viewer to have the needed PostScript fonts at hand. But usually the viewer and/or the printer only have very "similar" fonts which may differ slightly - leading to minor misplacements.

When using the **-Tdvi** option, the output is rendered for the *TeX* typesetter using TeX fonts. The resulting PDF code created by *dvipdf* includes the complete TeX font definitions. This leads to bigger output files but avoids further errors caused by font substitutions.

Thanks for bringing up this interesting question!

`*` ) I write PostScript-***like*** because I've did some testing and the results of **-Tpdf** differ badly from **-Tps** (which they shouldn't). In fact I now consider the PDF target as broken and would suggest to use **-Tps** and then convert the PostScript file to a PDF file)

Comment: This is a very clear answer, thank you!